# Jmeter only logs only first failed assertion to .jtl file

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, jmeter, assertions

*Edit: Jmeter version: 3.1 r1770033*

Im breaking my head on the following issue with Jmeter. I have tried several options including shifting around the order of the assertions. So far no result.

### **Functional wish**

Basically I want the .jtl log file to reflect the content of the 'assertion result' view in the Jmeter Gui mode.

### **Current setup**

I connect to a PostgreSQL database and execute a simple select from table query:

```
select * from progress_collaboration
```

This gives me the following resultset:

```
id  curr_env_id
999 1
```

On the sampler I have set 3 assertions:

- Size Assertion
- Response Assertion (string contains)
- Duration Assertion

## Problem

So far so good, up until only one assertion fails. When multiple assertions fail the 'assertion results' view shows me the following:
[assertionview image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e5hzr.png)

However, the .jtl logfile (created by running the project from the commandline) only contains the first failed assertion.

```
timeStamp,elapsed,label,responseCode,responseMessage,threadName,dataType,success,failureMessage,bytes,sentBytes,grpThreads,allThreads,Latency,IdleTime,Connect
1499254721391,455,Check Beheer Variable,200,OK,Thread Group 1-1,text,false,"The result was the wrong size: It was 21 bytes, but should have been equal to 170 bytes.",21,0,1,1,453,0,443
```

How do I ensure the .jtl logfile contains ALL failed assertions?

## Data

Hashtree with sampler and assertions:

```
        <JDBCSampler guiclass="TestBeanGUI" testclass="JDBCSampler" testname="Check Beheer Variable" enabled="true">
          <stringProp name="dataSource">myDatabase</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="query">select * from progress_collaboration</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="queryArguments"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="queryArgumentsTypes"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="queryTimeout"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="queryType">Select Statement</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="resultSetHandler">Store as String</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="resultVariable"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="variableNames"></stringProp>
        </JDBCSampler>
        <hashTree>
          <SizeAssertion guiclass="SizeAssertionGui" testclass="SizeAssertion" testname="Size Assertion" enabled="true">
            <stringProp name="Assertion.test_field">SizeAssertion.response_network_size</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="SizeAssertion.size">170</stringProp>
            <intProp name="SizeAssertion.operator">1</intProp>
          </SizeAssertion>
          <hashTree/>
          <ResponseAssertion guiclass="AssertionGui" testclass="ResponseAssertion" testname="Response Assertion" enabled="true">
            <collectionProp name="Asserion.test_strings">
              <stringProp name="56601">999</stringProp>
              <stringProp name="-715001365">incorrect_string</stringProp>
            </collectionProp>
            <stringProp name="Assertion.test_field">Assertion.response_data</stringProp>
            <boolProp name="Assertion.assume_success">true</boolProp>
            <intProp name="Assertion.test_type">2</intProp>
          </ResponseAssertion>
          <hashTree/>
          <DurationAssertion guiclass="DurationAssertionGui" testclass="DurationAssertion" testname="Duration Assertion" enabled="true">
            <stringProp name="DurationAssertion.duration">1000</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="Assertion.scope">all</stringProp>
          </DurationAssertion>
          <hashTree/>
        </hashTree>
```

Comment: Jmeter 3.1 or 3.2?

Comment: Good question, i forgot to mention. 3.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In jmeter.properties define/update propery:

jmeter.save.saveservice.assertion_results=all

(you probably have jmeter.save.saveservice.assertion_results=first defined)

Also listener should have Save as XML check box checked (inside Configure)

Comment: I was not aware of this properties file. I checked and this property was commented out. I have uncommented the property and added 'all' as value. Sadly it doesn't make a difference. Edit: After editing the properties I rebooted jmeter to make sure.

Comment: you need to restart jmeter. also make sure you don't have duplicate lines

Comment: add to solution - Also listener should have Save as XML check box checked (inside Configure)

Comment: When i save to XML I do get all the assertions. This works for me!

Comment: Thanks @user7294900